# How to add background color on left side of the page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I want to add background color on the left side of the page. I have main div which is centered and have fixed width. I tried background image but it's not working for me because I have infinite scroll on the page. Here is the picture which shows what I want to achieve:

[image]

And here is my approach:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="left"></div>
    <div class="container">
        my custom HTML code
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container {width: 1000px; margin: 0 auto}
.left {background-color: red; position: absolute; height: 100%; width:100%; top: 0px; left: -100%;  }
```

Comment: you have the right idea, but why do you have `left: -100%;`? change that to a positive value and you will have what you want. and set your `width` to something less than 100%

Comment: @stackErr It does not work for me.

Comment: look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/FeGFE/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the container on the center and the left side individual, here is it
http://jsfiddle.net/V6JaX/

```
.row { width: 100%; position: relative; }
.left { width: 20%; height: 100%; top: 0; left: 0; position: absolute; background: red; }
.container { width: 600px; margin: 0 auto; background: #FFF; }
```

Answer (score 4):

[Check out the fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/R749P/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="left">
        your left code
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        your custom HTML code
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container {
    background-color: gray;
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    float: left;
}

.left { 
    background-color: red;
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
}
```

Comment: Ok, so try replacing the widths with your fixed values. Why wouldn't it work?